# Get tooltip of label with specific attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-tooltip

I have many labels with tooltip value.

`label class="btn btn-default"  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Some title">XYZ </label>`

If the label is active then property looks like this.

```
'<label class="btn btn-default active"  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Some title">XYZ </label>'
```

Now I want to assign the tooltip value of the active label to variable using jquery.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, can you be a bit clear?

Comment: @PraveenKumar please check the question now, I've edited.

Comment: @hari Why don't you add a FIDDLE.

Comment: You want something in jQuery, but you haven't provided any jQuery code. Please show us what you've done in jQuery so far to accomplish this task.

Comment: @Sam , I haven't done anything so far. I'ma newbie , waiting for some solution, that I can merge into code

Comment: My suggestion is that you learn jQuery if you want jQuery solutions in your code. Read the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/ ... If we just give you code, it won't do you any good. Give a person a fish, they'll eat for a day. Teach a person to fish, they'll eat for a lifetime.

Comment: @Sam Thanks buddy for a great advice. Will work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/84hLxhsk/1/)

As far as i understand you want to get the value of tooltip text from jquery on elements having class `active`.

```
var $tooltip =  $('.active').attr('title');
```

documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

in case you want data attribute's value, you can use following value

```
var $datatitle = $('.active').data('original-title');
```

documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)